# wget working differently on 2 machines

Tags: download, server, wget, server-side, server-configuration

I'm trying to download a file using `wget`.
From my home machine it correctly downloads the mp3 file but when I try to run the same command from a Digital Ocean or Amazon VPS it downloads index.html file. It look like it does not receive the redirect and downloads for the first thing. 
I have not changed any config. The problem is probably between the 2 servers. The `wget` works correctly even on my jailbroken phone (home connection). The servers are Ubuntu 16 and the phone is iOS 9.3.3 (UNIX)

The command example  is:

```
wget http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=Mo2p4U20m2dLhkHKN3xL2S9boAc8zr4iCOgxH9FrWE9qgN6Sn6Idmyc87NeFU9D13c%2BrjZMsPByg8EqrPCi%2FvQ --content-disposition
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

---

Ok so I have tried running the `wget` on my phone via cellular connection (not WiFi) and it "works" the same as DO, Amazon. So the downloading only works from my home IP correctly. Does anyone know how to solve it?

---

Ok now it does not even work from home IP. I guess the server (probably cloud-flare) is blocking the requests. If anyone knows if you can bypass it, please share.